# How to fix the song playing over every icon?

Tags: html, audio, icons

This is the code I have, and displays correctly as seen here.

[image]

The issue is if you press any of the play icons, it will only play the last song that is in the listed code. I have attempted to make spacing changes and I end up only being able to play the first song instead, and it spans over all of the icons. I'm really not sure how to fix this and would love some help.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css"  />

<div class="col-xl-4 col-md-6 p-1">
  <div class="card h-100 d-block bg-faded card-block">
    <div class="display-4 text-uppercase text-center text-primary" style="font-size:18px;letter-spacing:2px;">
      Playlist
    </div>
    <hr class="my-1">
    <div class="text-muted" style="max-height:257px;">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/miy6aK6btgU?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity:.001" class="h-20 w-25" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="text-muted" style="float: right;">Joy - Bastille</span>
      <hr class="my-1">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sEnt9KhNHvA?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity:.001" class="h-20 w-25" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="text-muted" style="float: right;">Nobody - Hozier</span>
      <hr class="my-1">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bbf-U6G9ndU?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity:.001" class="h-20 w-25" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="text-muted" style="float: right;">The Anchor - Bastille</span>
      <hr class="my-1">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xarC5jAiO7w?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity:.001" class="h-20 w-25" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="text-muted" style="float: right;">A Moment Apart - Odesza</span>
      <hr class="my-1">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ut8Nn_hoV80?modestbranding=1" style="position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; opacity:.001" class="h-20 w-25" frameborder="0"></iframe>
      <i class="fas fa-play fa-fw"></i>
      <span class="text-muted" style="float: right;">Sweet Creature - Harry Styles</span>
      <hr class="my-1">
    </div>
```

Comment: I tried to create a [mcve] - please add relevant CSS and HTML and add `</i>`

Comment: Where is the script that actually plays the music? It seems all the iFrames are in the same position, so whatever is loaded last is what will play if that is how this works

Comment: @mplungjan I've closed the i and no different. The iframe is what is playing, I tried to change their positions and ended up with the same problem, except with it only playing the first song. Sorry, I'm very new to coding and this website!